# Why do people say that smallpox has been eradicated?

Tags: virology

I keep reading things like “smallpox has been eradicated” or “there are only two samples of the virus left in existence in a lab somewhere”, but couldn’t there be a bunch of smallpox viruses in an alleyway where some infected person sneezed years ago? Is there some reason the virus can’t exist without a human host?

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://westhunt.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/weaponizing-smallpox).

Answer (score 4):

The viruses that caused smallpox (Variola major and Variola minor) are generally not stable in the environment (<24 hours as an aerosol), though they may persist for more than a decade within scabs [Reviewed: Sinclair et. al., 2008](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2227740) [OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/smallpox/controls.html).

UV light is an excellent disinfectant, so typically any virus exposed to sunlight will lose rapidly infectiousness.

You may also find this answer to a related question of interest:
https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59165/46609